# Unity3D: Collider expands when the game starts

Tags: 2d, unity-game-engine, physics

In the past days, I learned how to animate and good ways to create them and after a while, a little gap between the player attracted my attention.
[image: The error graphical explained]
(No gap when the game hasn't started)
[image: The error graphical explained]
(A little gap when the game has started)

First, I searched on google if people had the same problem, so I found the setting "Min Penetration For Penalty" under the **project settings physics2D** and I didn't find it.
*Next step.*
So I have searched again recently. One guy in a Unity forum said, that this mentioned setting has been removed long ago + it was upgraded to "Default Contact Offset".
Link to the forum -> http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/991900/physics-settings-missing-parameters.html
But as I tried to change this parameter, I could do it **less than 0.0001** and the gap was still there.

I hope you can help me with this annoying problem to get this gap away from my character (in-game) and that he doesn't fly over the ground.

Comment: it seems to me the colliders are ok. in fact, it's your player that's moving up and not the colliders moving down. It's clearly visible. So I think you need to look in that direction, maybe your sprite is a child of the parent with a collider and animator is messing with its position?

Comment: No. The sprite is not a child of a other object and the Animator ist only changing the animation but he isn't messing with some 2D colliders.